# How to display methods from a random element in Arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist, random

I know how to get a random element from `ArrayList`, but what I don't know is how to also display only 1 element's methods. For example, I have two subclasses with a few methods that are very basic (they basically just print some stuff), and the `ArrayList` is in the superclass.

This is my code with the Cat and Dog being subclasses. Now the code prints one of them but methods from both classes are displayed. If the program picks Dog for example, then I want only the results from Dog's `noise()` and `furr()` to be displayed. How could I do this?

```
ArrayList<Animal> an = new ArrayList<>();
        an.add(new Cat());
        an.add(new Dog());

       for (Animal a : an) { 
        a.noise();
        a.furr();
    }
   
    int randomIndex = (int) (Math.random() * an.size());
    System.out.println( "The animal: " +  an.get( randomIndex ));
```

Comment: By doing this you are breaking one of the basics of oop: polymorphism. When you put the elements into a list, you should treat all of the items as Animals. Your animal class or interface should be rich enough to be useful so that it all could be called with Animal methods. For example, Animal.noise() which would be overridden in both Cat and Dog to make different sounds. Perhaps Animal.skin() would be overridden for both dog, cat, and parrot.

Answer (score 1):

You're looping through all animals and calling Animal#noise and Animal#furr. What you want to do instead is get the animal at the index you've selected and call those methods on that one instance.

It's also worth mentioning that it's unconventional to allow classes to have more than one responsibility. When the `Animal` super class maintains a `List` with `Animal` references you break this convention. Instead, use a pattern like the `service locator pattern` to avoid this.

```java
int randomIndex = (int) (Math.random() * an.size());

Animal animal = an.get(randomIndex);

animal.noise();
animal.furr();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method for that after you select the random element pass it to a method then print it. I find it for you.

```
public int getRandomElement(List<Integer> list) 
{ 
    Random rand = new Random(); 
    return list.get(rand.nextInt(list.size())); 
}
```